# Flash Builder bug?

Tags: actionscript-3, mxml, flash-builder

Irritatingly, Flash Builder refuses to implement any changes I make to the program when I run it. I can't find any documentation of this anywhere online after a brief googling, just wondering if anyone has come across this problem before and/or found a solution? I don't want to have to export a release build every time I want to check if any changes have been implemented successfully (I'm just assuming that'd work)

It happened to me once before but I overcame this problem simply by starting a new project as there wasn't much of any significance, and couldn't easily fix it.

It's pretty much as simple as it sounds tbh, having returned to my computer a couple of hours after leaving it I find any changes to any part of the code have no impact on what is displayed when I go to run...

Any insight would be much appreciated

Thanks

Josh

Comment: That is pretty vague. What are you doing? Does Flash Builder generate a swf?

Comment: Thanks for the additional feedback.

Comment: I am encoutering the same issue. It is not a browser cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be the cache of your browser. Clear your cache and see if that works..

It could also be because you have classes that are compiled in external swf's. If you compile in Flash Builder, you're not persee recompiling those classes. Instead, compile the external swf which has links to those classes.

Answer (score 0):

You'd think if this were a bug in Flash Builder, people would be complaining about it a bit more often, check that your browser is updating properly, most likely you've got the SWF stuck in your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "clear application data on each launch" in Run/Debug Configuration window.

This will clear and uninstall existing app installed in your test device, so every new launch will have clean build.

Tips : Make sure to cmd/ctr + B first, In every run/build.